# Some class in scala - Map side join in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is my code .

```
val ss  =  SparkSession.builder()
                       .appName("broadcastvariable")
                       .master("local")
                       .getOrCreate()

val sq  =  ss.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("UK","UN","US","IN"))

val mp  =  Map("UK"->"United Kingdom","US"->"United State","IN"-> "India")

val br  =  ss.sparkContext.broadcast(mp)

val newVal  =  sq.map(f=>br.value.get(f))

newVal.foreach(f=> println(f))
```

and I am getting below output.

```
Some(United Kingdom)
None
Some(United State)
Some(India)
```

Why am I getting `Some(United Kingdom)` instead of just `United Kingdom` and how do I get only `United kingdom` instead of `Some(United kingdom)`.